# Counting without using group By

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello All I want to use subquery,
In sub query There is not possible to count using Group By function therefore I want to count without Group by function for multiple fetching  Column

```
 Select  Count (STS_FK_GLUSR_ID) 
 from STS_DSR_SALES@mainr, STS_company@mainr 
 where STS_DSR_SALES.FK_STS_company_id = fk_STS_COMPANY_ID
     and STS_company.STS_FK_GLUSR_ID = STS_FK_GLUSR_ID



SAMPLE DATA

STS_DSR_SALES_DATE|STS_FK_GLUSR_ID
22-4-2019         |291
24-4-2019         |245
29-4-2019         |345
26-4-2019         |346
24-4-2019         |256
24-4-2019         |256
26-4-2019         |346

My expected Result is 

STS_FK_GLUSR_ID| count
291            |1
245            |1
345            |1
346            |2
256            |2
```

Comment: Please make this a concrete question by a) including sample data and the desired output, and b) removing incompatible database tags.  You can't be using SQL Server and Oracle at the same time.

Comment: Removed SQLServer, as he has mentioned ORACLE-SQLDeveloper as the client

Comment: There is no Group By function - that is a clause. Why is it not possible to count using Group By? Start with that.

Comment: Whoever manages to answer this, I want to know how you did it.

Comment: because I want to use this query as sub query and its not possible to use it in Subquery as it gives Too many Values error

Comment: "too many values"? Then you are using it wrong.

Comment: I doubt a subquery gives "too many values error" - whatever that mean. Please describe your requirements properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you like to use a sub-query?

Simply use

```
Select Count (STS_DSR_SALES_DATE), STS_FK_GLUSR_ID
from STS_DSR_SALES@mainr, STS_company@mainr 
where STS_DSR_SALES.FK_STS_company_id = fk_STS_COMPANY_ID
     and STS_company.STS_FK_GLUSR_ID = STS_FK_GLUSR_ID
GROUP BY STS_FK_GLUSR_ID;
```

Comment: i HAVE TO USE IN gROUP BY

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Please don't edit my answer with your query. Instead put it in your question. Your code has several syntax errors. (and please check your caps-lock key)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with my crystal ball.

Reading comments posted so far, I think this is something you're doing; invalid, though, because subquery returns two columns (`count` and `STS_FK_GLUSR_ID9` while `some_column` is only one:

```
select *
from some_table
where some_column = (
                    -- this is your query with GROUP BY clasue
                    Select  STS_company.STS_FK_GLUSR_ID,
                            Count (STS_FK_GLUSR_ID) 
                    from STS_DSR_SALES@mainr, STS_company@mainr 
                    where STS_DSR_SALES.FK_STS_company_id = fk_STS_COMPANY_ID
                      and STS_company.STS_FK_GLUSR_ID = STS_FK_GLUSR_ID
                    --
                    group by STS_company.STS_FK_GLUSR_ID
                   )
```

As your query returns 5 rows, you can't say `some_column =`.

But, you might try with `some_column in` instead.

Here's how it might look like; `count` removed, `having` added:

```
select *
from some_table
where some_column in (
                      Select  STS_company.STS_FK_GLUSR_ID
                      from STS_DSR_SALES@mainr join STS_company@mainr 
                           on STS_DSR_SALES.FK_STS_company_id = fk_STS_COMPANY_ID
                          and STS_company.STS_FK_GLUSR_ID     = STS_FK_GLUSR_ID
                      --
                      group by STS_company.STS_FK_GLUSR_ID
                      having count(*) > 1
                     )
```

If this doesn't ring a bell, well, consider posting what you really have and what you'd want to get from that, i.e. post complete test case (`create table` and `insert into`).